# Where can i get "import com.google.json" the json jar

Tags: json

I cannot find the jar for json while trying build the sample application "LatencyDashboard" provided with speedtracer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's this you want:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

Comment: nops, that is not "import com.google.json.*" i included the gson-1.5.jar but having  the same isssue:

Comment: Yes, but I think that may have been an old name for it, I couldn't find any reference to com.google.json, and this project is Google's JSON parser/formatter. I suspect you either need to dig through the old versions or update the code I'm afraid! As a hack you could get the source jar for Gson and just re-factor it in eclipse to be in that package, and then re-jar it?